# What is the current state of research in Chern-Simons theory?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-topology, topological-quantum-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

I'm a PhD student in mathematical physics looking for some orientation. As asked in the title, I would like to know the current state of research in Chern-Simons theory. More specifically, what are some of the directions that people are currently pursuing in this field.

I did not ask for more general topological field theories, but this is largely due to personal interests. Of course, answers related to other TFTs are more than welcome.

I feel this question has been asked before. But since this is a question about the current state of research, I think it deserves an update.

Thank you very much.

Comment: this book from 2009 gives an overview of open problems, and for a mature field such as this it should be recent enough: https://books.google.nl/books?id=Qex4AAAAQBAJ